# How do I move from my html file to another html file to create an iOS hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

I'd like to replace a `webView` page with a `Spring-MVC` structure with a **hybrid** format So I'd like to replace the `JSP` file with an `HTML` file and put it in the `ios project folder`.

This part successfully inserted the html test file, and the `html` load was also successful.

The problem is the current page file should be moved to other html in a file that is. Previously, the address of the page controller file was managed by Java, and the page was moved to the address value, but now the html file must be displayed.

**current PageController**

```java
public class PageController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "/index";
    }
...
```

**current move page**

```js
function pagemove(_url) {
    location.href =  _url; // url: "/nextPage"
}
```

**curerent WebViewLoad**

```swift
func loadWebPage(_ webUrl : String) {
        guard let myUrl = URL(string: webUrl) else {
            //report invalid URL
            return
        }
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
        WKWebView.load(myRequest)
    }
```

Now I'm moving the screen in this way. How can I move if I switch to HTML?

**Loading Web Views from iOS(testing)**

```swift
func loadWebPage(_ webUrl : String) {
   let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HTMLFolder/testweb", withExtension: "html")!
   let myRequest = URLRequest(url: localFilePath)

   WKWebView.load(myRequest)
}
```

**I'm using Swift5**

I want to go to the **testwebTwo.HTML** file from the **testweb.HTML** file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your project is managed through a server built in `Java`. But now you have to move your page through the `html` file inside the `ios` project.

There are two ways in order to so.

Firstly, if you load a webView into an `html` file, your webView looks at the path to the project file.
Therefore, when you move pages, you can also specify a path. An example is an example of how `html` files are in the **same path** and created.

```js
function pagemove(_url) {
    location.href =  _url; // url: "./testwebTwo.html"
}
```

Second, you can load page data by sending and receiving messages through `js` and `native` communication.

**js function**

```js
    function testMovePage() {
      var data = {};
      data.movePage = "HTMLFolder/testwebTwo";
      try {
        webkit.messageHandlers.yourMessageKey.postMessage(data);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    }
```

**Receive From Swift**

```swift
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "yourMessageKey" {
            let sendmessage = message.body as! NSDictionary

            guard sendmessage["movePage"] != nil else {
                return
            }
           let urlString : String = sendmessage["movePage"] as! String
           let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: urlString, withExtension: "html")
           let request = URLRequest(url: filePath)
            WKWebView.load(request)
            ...
```